# Add reusable navigation menu to HTML pages

Tags: php, javascript, include, client-side, server-side

Currently, my website uses static hand-written HTML pages. I add navigation menu to all the pages manually.
I want to be able to maintain a single user resource file that contains the HTML code for the menu and reference to this file from all the other HTML files on the website.
I know we can do this using server side includes and client side includes. But after reading the pros and cons of each method, I am confused about which method should I use for my situation.

P.S. My server is not a PHP server.

Thanks!

Comment: 1. php is not a server. either your server runs php scripts or it doesn't.

Comment: Only you can decide which solution is best for your situation. If you've read up on the different options you have all the information you need.

Comment: You could use a CMS. There are a number of things this could be built with, ASP.NET, JAVA, PHP, RUBY, GRAILS, ect... Or you could even do it with JavaScript / jQuery. This question is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: If you don't want to use a server side script language, you can use a frameset — which would be "server side". Definitely better than using JavaScript on the client side, which might be disabled by some users! If you want us to help deciding, you should write down the options in consideration.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, you want the site to load faster and be easy to maintain. If you use client-side javascript to perform AJAX in order to get the modules/widgets, then you are adding more http requests, and the site will get noticeably slower. Using the server to assemble pages works, but then you lose the advantage of javascript animations and AJAX. A mixture of both server and client may be confusing, but could be optimal. If your server is Node.JS you have a huge advantage, as the same functions on the server can be configured to work for the client.

For example, You may use the server for things like assembling the nav bar as part of the index file, and using the client to load things like the updated nav bar after a user logs in via ajax. It's possible to use the same functions on Node and in the browser- for example, jQuery or YUI are available in node.

So it really depends on your server, and how much work you want to do.

By far, the easiest and quickest solution I can give you is to use server-side templating. Not knowing your server, using jQuery and the load method is useful for client-side template-loading.

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load

Comment: Thank you all for the detailed responses. I am using Amazon S3 to host my site. Can you please tell me if PHP scripts will work on S3? P.S. I am a complete noob to web technologies and that is the reason my questions might sound vague.

Answer (score 1):

Flat HTML files cannot be included into each other. You'll have to use one or another server-side scripting language.

Is your server some flavor of Apache (Linux)? if yes, it will probably be php-enabled. Check with your hosting provider.

However it may be, the rules of thumb are as follows (applicable to any backend framework, but detailed as relelvant to php):

1) code up your nav, on one HTML page

2) save it as a php file (or follow the procedure for whatever you have one the server-side -- from now on I continue on the the assumption you'll be using php)

3) save all your pages as .php, in order to be able to include your new reusable element

4) replace nav section HTML in all pages with the php include statement, including your navigation file, eg nav.php 
   eg,

```
  include( $path . 'nav.php')
```

5) if you wish to include "you-are-here" highlighting, 
  a) set an id on the body tag on all pages
  b) set an id on each of the links in your included nav.php

6) in your CSS, list all possible combinations of page id & nav link id, eg

```
  #homepage #homeLink, 
  #contactPage #contactLink,
  #aboutPage #aboutLink {

  /* format your "active" nav link here */

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

alternatively you can use Jquery's .load() function to load another a text file into the nav (it loads as html if html tags are used in the txt file) but this would be useless if the user has JavaScript disabled.

See Jquery documentation link bellow

http://api.jquery.com/load/